# Find Taylor Series of $(3x^2 + 2x -7)e^{5x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

What would be the easiest way I would be able to find the Taylor series of $$f(x) = (3x^2 + 2x -7)e^{5x}$$

I was reading I have to find the first few derivatives but I am not sure how helpful that is with this function. I was thinking of also using the fact that the Taylor series of $$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ but i am not sure how to. Any advice?

Comment: Just multiply the series with the polynomial

Comment: Finding the first derivatives in $z=0$ to find Taylor expansions is usually not the good way. In your case, it is preferable to expand $(3x^2 + 2x -7)e^{5x} =(3x^2 + 2x -7)(1+5x+\tfrac{1}{2!}(5x)^2+ \tfrac{1}{3!}(5x)^3+\cdots$

Answer (score 3):

Writing the Taylor series for $e^{5x}$ and multiply it by $3x^2+2x-7$ is the easiest way. To find the Taylor series for $e^{5x}$ write the series for $e^x$ and replace $x$ with $5x$.